# How to hide gridlines in an excel sheet through C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, excel, visibility, gridlines

Following this

```
http://www.e-iceblue.com/Tutorials/Spire.XLS/Spire.XLS-Program-Guide/Worksheet/How-to-hide-or-show-gridlines-on-a-worksheet-in-C.html
```

to hide gridlines I should do just:

```
Workbook wb = app.Workbooks.Add(XlWBATemplate.xlWBATWorksheet);
  Worksheet ws = wb.Worksheets[1];
   ws.GridLinesVisible = false;<----WRONG
```

but that is wrong.

And also the solution here

> [How to disable gridlines in Excel using open xml C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14230538/how-to-disable-gridlines-in-excel-using-open-xml-c)

does not work. So any other method?

thank you in advance.
PAtrick

Comment: Why is it "WRONG"? Does it give an error? Does it not compile?

Comment: Because it does not compile. I thought it was not wpf

Comment: You are following a tutorial for a library (`Spire.XLS`)... are you actually using that library?

Comment: So awkward of me ...no i didn t noticed it. Any other way to set excel gridlines off with no added library?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

With no third party library, using only the simple Excel interop (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel), it should work with this:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application xlApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();

xlApp.Visible = true;

Workbook wb = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(XlWBATemplate.xlWBATWorksheet);
Worksheet ws = wb.Worksheets[1];

xlApp.ActiveWindow.DisplayGridlines = false;
```

Comment: Any info on how to hide gridlines on multiple sheets? I only seem to be able to get it on the `ActiveWindow` (the first sheet).

Answer (score 0):

For multiple sheets and working with Excel interop, activate each sheet first.

```
worksheet.Activate();
xlApp.ActiveWindow.DisplayGridlines = false;
```

Hope this helps those that need to deal with multiple sheets.